# How to put type constraint on data type in idris

Tags: idris

In idris, how can I constraint the type of parameters in Algebraic Data Type ?

In haskell, I would have done :

```
data Foo = Bar {x :: Integer, str :: String}
```

Can I do that in Idris ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options: data types

```
data Foo = Bar Int String
```

or records

```
record Foo : Type where
  Bar : (x : Int) -> (str : String) -> Foo
```

Both have some limitations: in case of data types you don't have named accessors, in case of records you can have only one constructor.

You can find a bit more information about datatypes and records in [Idris tutorial](http://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/writings/idris-tutorial.pdf) in sections **3.2 Data Types** and **3.11 Dependent Records**